# ADO.NET connectors in machine.config aren't returned by

Tags: ado.net

In the machine.config on one system we have:

```
<system.data> 
<DbProviderFactories> 
<add name="Odbc Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.Odbc" 
description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Odbc" 
type="System.Data.Odbc.OdbcFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/> 
<add name="OleDb Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OleDb" 
description=".Net Framework Data Provider for OleDb" 
type="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/> 
<add name="OracleClient Data Provider" 
invariant="System.Data.OracleClient" description=".Net Framework Data 
Provider for Oracle" type="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleClientFactory, 
System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/> 
<add name="SqlClient Data Provider" 
invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data 
Provider for SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, 
System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/> 
<add name="IBM DB2 for i .NET Provider" 
invariant="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries" description=".NET Framework Data Provider 
for IBM i" type="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, 
Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cdb2ebfb1f93a26" /> 
</DbProviderFactories> 
</system.data>
```

However DbProviderFactories returns nothing. Not even the OleDB or ODBC providers. The app.exe.config file has no  section and therefore no .

What can be blocking this?

Comment: You have 2 machine.config files, are you checking the correct one? (Framework and Framework64 folders)

Comment: Yes - that was the first thing I looked at.

Comment: Have you tried removing the IBM entry - and this looks like a .NET 2.0 machine.config, is that what your app uses (and no 4.0) ?